# Minecraft: How to teleport players using a distant command block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

> I want a command block at (0,0,0), so that when a player steps on the pressure plate at (0,0,100), he gets teleported to (0,0,200), while other players who are not on the pressure plate should not be affected.

What is the suitable command? Thank you.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Why does it have to be at 0 0 0? Also, have you tried just putting the command in it? It should work. Except if you want to activate the command block with redstone, but that's not necessary.

Comment: @Frank: I did attempt to solve this problem, and I fail because of lack of knowledge: the only method I know to teleport a particular player is to use @p, which is not useful here. Can you please give me some direction?

Comment: @ Fabian: I just want the command block to be far away enough so that the player will not see it (my map has nearly no barrier that can hide it). I did not manage to teleport that particular player.

Comment: Pressure plate on top of stone block (or whatever) on top of command block, where is the problem? It's not visible by the player.

Comment: I am making a 3D maze where the player will go up and down in a very small area, the surrounding of the stone is visible.

Comment: You should add what you've tried to your question. That way, we have something to work with. From the comments, it sounds like you could flesh it out with additional details.

Answer (score 1):

Always active repeating command block:

```
execute @a 0 0 100 detect ~ ~ ~ stone_pressure_plate powered:true tp @s 0 0 200
```

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/execute as @a if block 0 0 100 stone_pressure_plate[powered=true] run tp @s 0 0 200`

Answer (score 1):

You could also use:

```
tp @a[x=0,y=0,z=100,r=1] 0 0 200
```

This command block would be <kbd>Repeat</kbd> <kbd>Unconditional</kbd> <kbd>Always Active</kbd>
This will not require the pressure plate.  As soon as a player gets to (0,0,100) they will be teleported.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/tp @a[x=0,y=0,z=100,distance=..1] 0 0 200`